# 4 Panel Double Line Plot with Two Y-Axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a graph that has 4 panels, 1 for each 'Male'.  Each panel will have two lines, one for each y axis.  The first y axis has 'A' on the left and the second y-axis would have 'B' on the right y-axis.  The x-axis doesn't represent anything other than the fact that there are 15 measurements per male.  I want to set limits for each y-axis as well.  The limits are as follows:

Male 548 (40,58) and (2600,3100)
Male 594 (36,54) and (3400,3900)
Male 331 (42,60) and (3500,3700)
Male 126 (35,49) and (3000,4200)

I don't need a legend and can figure out different line styles, colors, and axis labels I think.  The only quirk might be if I want one overall axis label on the left side of the plots labelled 'A' and one axis label on the right side of the plots labelled 'B', so the axis labels aren't overly redundant.

I really have no idea where to start because there are two issues:  the 4 panels and each panel having two y-axes.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
structure(list(Male = c(594L, 594L, 594L, 594L, 594L, 594L, 594L, 
594L, 594L, 594L, 594L, 594L, 594L, 594L, 594L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 
548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 
548L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 
331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 331L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 
126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L), A = c(53.07, 
46.91, 48.02, 43.36, 41.32, 39.69, 41.25, 43.9, 43.24, 41.48, 
37.22, 38.04, 37.5, 38.88, 37.51, 57.23, 51.97, 46.85, 51.02, 
41.56, 51.23, 44.79, 50.87, 46.6, 56.22, 46.98, 49.04, 50.07, 
46.32, 48.75, 53.62, 58.19, 51.29, 51.85, 55.28, 55.66, 54.14, 
49.4, 49.87, 44.81, 44.23, 47.99, 45.46, 44.9, 42.09, 43.36, 
44.52, 44.77, 49.08, 47.88, 39.24, 41.75, 48.63, 49.95, 43.57, 
41.94, 37.74, 40.97, 45.56, 45.65), B = c(3833.4, 3692.7, 3625, 
3630, 3589.7, 3506.9, 3501.6, 3606.2, 3580.6, 3530, 3479.7, 3512, 
3510.9, 3484.5, 3535.5, 2973.9, 2948.8, 2715.2, 2980.4, 2693.6, 
2888.4, 2718.5, 2971, 2752.2, 3008.5, 2718.4, 2860.2, 2848, 2893.3, 
2940.2, 3526.7, 3592.9, 3588.2, 3614.1, 3619.2, 3625.8, 3574.8, 
3650, 3678.2, 3655.6, 3675.3, 3681.3, 3680.7, 3647.5, 3670, 3640, 
3360.8, 3309.4, 3101.1, 3263.3, 3070, 3153.3, 3594, 4220, 3670, 
3367.9, 3156.7, 3431, 3440.5, 3276.7)), .Names = c("Male", "A", 
"B"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to give you a Lattice/LatticeExtra solution because there's no easy way to get ggplot2 to make a second y-axis. I'm assuming your original data set is named `dd`. Then I would do

```
require(lattice)
require(latticeExtra)
pd<-dd
pd$Male<-factor(pd$Male)
pd$idx <- ave(rep(1, nrow(pd)), pd$Male, FUN=seq_along)
mA<-xyplot(A~idx|Male, data=pd, type="l")
mB<-xyplot(B~idx|Male, data=pd, type="l")
doubleYScale(mA, mB)
```

And that produces

[image: panel plot with double Y]

Here all the ranges are the same so you can more directly compare the samples.

If you really want separate y-axis for each plot then try

```
free.y <- list(y=list(relation="free"))
mA <- xyplot(A~idx|Male, data=pd, type="l", scales=free.y)
mB <- xyplot(B~idx|Male, data=pd, type="l", scales=free.y)
comb <- doubleYScale(mA, mB)
comb$x.between <- 5 #(add space otherwise panels touch)
comb
```

[image: panel plot with double free y axis]

Comment: This is close for sure, but the cool data correlations are lost without each panel having its own scaled y-axes.  The patterns are sort of visible, but aren't quite powerful this way.  Is there a way to fix that or is this a limit of 'Lattice'?  Either way, this is much better than I could do, but would still like others to try for a slightly more modified answer if possible.

Comment: @user3494534 I've updated with code that will allow different y-value ranges for each plot

Comment: No we're cooking with Crisco!  This looks like I envisioned.  By adding axes for each plot separately, it really lets you visualize these correlations (or lack thereof) much more clearly.  Thank you for your time and help!  I believe I can adjust minor things as needed from here.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the 'Male' label strips at the top?  Also, are the fine tune controls like line color, type, axis tick scale, axis label colors, and axis labels, controlled with Lattice or latticeExtra?

Comment: @user3494534 Most of those are controlled via the lattice `xyplot` function. I encourage you to read more about the library via the help pages. If you have additional formatting question, please open a new question rather than asking in comments so that others might be able to help as well.